# multi-environment deployment with Vlad and nginx

Tags: nginx, deployment, vlad-deployer

I'd like to be able to deploy staging and production environments with Vlad the Deployer. I've created a separate task for each environment, since each environment is prepared differently. Now I am trying to organize nginx configurations. Should I create two separate nginx configs, put them into `sites-enabled` folder and include them in nginx.conf?

Comment: You will need two nginx configurations as staging and production will have two domains pointing to different paths. I find a combination of passenger standalone, rvm, nginx, and Ubuntu Upstart (for starting the standalone instances using sockets) to work well (also enables use of any Ruby for each app).

Answer (score 0):

I think it is depends on complexity of your environments. Some files in sites-enabled folder allows you to have more clean structure. But if you have only two servers and it described by 10 lines, it isn't necessary.